# How to target content after table with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, phpquery

I have some content mixed with html elements. I want to target description section. Hovewer description doesn't have any div or other elements around it, so I can't target it by class.

Description is in `<p>` elements, and goes right after Table.contacts-table. How can I target this area with jQuery ?

```
<div class="main-content">
        <a class="btn pull-right back-to-list">Atgal į renginių sąrašą</a>
        <h2>Vilniaus dokumentinių filmų festivalis (VDFF)</h2>
        <table border="0" class="contacts-table">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="td1 marker">Renginio vieta:</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="td1 pdf" colspan="2">
                        <a href="download.php?id=33039">PROGRAMA</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table><!-- Kino centras „Skalvija“, kino teatras „Pasaka“ --><br>

        <!--- START OF DESCRIPTION -->

        <p style="text-align: justify;">Rugsėjui perkopus į antrąją pusę
        sostinėje įsiplieks reikšmingiausius dokumentinius filmus pristatantis
        festivalis..</p>
        <p style="text-align: justify;"></p>
        <p style="text-align: justify;">Festivalio programą sudarys naujausi
        dokumentiniai filmai iš viso pasaulio, bus parodyta ukrainiečio
        Sergejaus Bukovskio filmų retrospektyva</p>
        <p style="text-align: justify;">Daugiau informacijos: <a href=
        "http://www.vdff.lt">www.vdff.lt</a></p><br>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like `$('.main-content > p')` works nice for the provided markup.

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/e7hn3gv3/

---

EDIT

More specifically, if you need everything after the table (in case you have paragraphs before it), you can do:

```
$('.main-content > table').nextAll();
```

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/e7hn3gv3/1/ (notice the paragraph before the table not showing in the output)

Answer (score 1):

This is really a css question. You would select the first p after the table with:

```
table.contacts-table + p
```

or select all of them with:

`table.contacts-table ~ p`

Comment: There's more than just one P.